# Mindstorm EV3 no longer recognises SD card

Tags: mindstorms, ev3

I followed the instructions to install [leJOS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lejos/) on an SD card, to get Java support for the Mindstorms EV3 brio. The brick detected the leJOS files and processed the whole installation procedure successfully. However, at the end of the installation process the brick rebooted. Since then the SD card is no longer recognised by the brick.

I tried to format the SD card again to repeat the installation procedure, but the brick boots into the standard menu without recognising the SD card.

Any idea to get the SD card working again?

Comment: I would suggest posting this question on the leJOS forum - I've seen many similar issues coming by there and you will get a better and faster response there - leJOS is not official LEGO software and is hence not fully within scope of this forum. The leJOS forum is here: http://www.lejos.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=17

Comment: Maybe just use USB because there is USB slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [leJOS](http://www.lejos.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=17) forum posts, I think your best bet is to try another SD card and use the officially recommended SD card creator tools to format and populate your new card.